# How to auto increment a property in razor pages

Tags: asp.net, auto-increment, razor-pages, litedb

I have a property for my inventorynumbers and I want to auto increment it (LiteDB, asp.net Core 3.1 razor pages) the property is a string! Is that possible???

Comment: How do you want increment String _id? By int number? There is no AutoId support for String because there is no rule for that

Comment: Solved! I split my string “xyz - 113” and parse it to int... and then just lncrement the int